# Why my PHP MYSQL query not working/running after i enter this query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables **tableOne = 90K** data and **tableTwo = 100k** data, i will look for the duplicate numbers on both tables with the given conditions and the matching must be **1:1** if multiple match are on the other table only one will be tagged as match (given that the data on both tables has match data).

I have this select statement below, but when i run it on my local xampp and even on CMD the screen freezes after i press enter then it takes hours before it returns an error out of memory. Hope you can help me with this.

```
 SELECT rNum,
        cDate,
        cTime,
        aNumber,
        bNumber,
        duration,
        tag,
        aNumber2,
        bNumber2,
        'hasMatch',
        concatDate,
        timeMinutes
        FROM tableOne a
        LEFT JOIN
        tableTwo b ON a.aNumber2 = b.aNumber2 
        AND a.bNumber2 = b.bNumber2
        WHERE a.hasMatch = 'valid'
        AND (a.duration - b.duration) <= 3  
        AND (a.duration - b.duration) >= -3 
        AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) <= 3
        AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) >= -3
```

Thank you In advance.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If the query hangs from the command line as well, you should remove the PHP-tag, since that isn't a part of your actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing 1:1 relationship with two tables then I think you should probably go with INNER JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN

Secondly, your query doesn't seem to be indexed properly. So, better would be using EXPLAIN SELECT ... to see the profile of SQL and create INDEXES for Filters.

Comment: Thank you for responding. i am not that familiar with Explain select yet because i am just a newbie in MYSQL will try it later. For the indexes those 2 tables came from different departments so basically it was just passed to me, and i need to find the matches just based on the aNumber2 and bNumber2 with the conditions on the duration and concatDate.

Answer (score 0):

1. in your `SELECT` you have `aNumber2` and based on your join rule both table `a` and table `b` have `aNumber2` column. it's a problem. if two table have a column with the same name, on select you should specify the table.
   for example like this

   `SELECT a.aNumber2 as a_number2,....`

in your query the same problem exists for other columns like `duration` and `concatDate`

2. another thing is you should use `INNER JOIN` in your case instead of `LEFT JOIN`.
3. if you final result have many rows(thousands), take them step by step... add `LIMIT` to your example and take 100 result each time.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i forgot to include the a.fields on the copied statement.

Comment: I have the statement like this now, however i am not that familiar with LIMIT where i can continue the count after the last one on the first 100 results. 
SELECT a.rNum,a.cDate,a.cTime,a.aNumber,a.bNumber,a.duration,a.tag,a.aNumber2,a.bNumber2,'hasMatch',a.concatDate,a.timeMinutes
FROM tableOne a
INNER JOIN
tableTwo b ON a.aNumber2 = b.aNumber2 
AND a.bNumber2 = b.bNumber2
WHERE a.hasMatch = 'valid'
AND (a.duration - b.duration) <= 3  
AND (a.duration - b.duration) >= -3 
AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) <= 3
AND TIMEDIFF(a.concatDate,b.concatDate) >= -3

Comment: add ` LIMIT 100,0` to end of your query. it gives you the first 100 result. then try it with ` LIMIT 100,100` , ` LIMIT 100,200`,... to get next results

Comment: Thank you sir, i tried that already but during LIMIT 1001,100 it takes an hour before i receive the result, i am only using my local for DB and only have 4G(3.4G usable) RAM, does it affects the performance of the query? Thank you